# Python email bot Pyzmail/IMAPclient error

Tags: python, keyerror, imapclient

So I'm working on a Python script to extract text from an email and following [these instructions](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter16/) to do so. This is the script thus far:

```
import imapclient
import pprint
import pyzmail

mymail = "my@email.com"
password = input("Password: ")

imapObj = imapclient.IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com' , ssl=True)
imapObj.login(mymail , password)
imapObj.select_folder('INBOX', readonly=False)
UIDs = imapObj.search(['SUBJECT Testing'])
rawMessages = imapObj.fetch([5484], ['BODY[]'])
message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessages[5484]['BODY[]'])
```

However I'm getting this error:

```
message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessages[5484]['BODY[]'])
KeyError: 5484
```

5484 being the ID for the email that the search function finds. I've also tried putting UIDs in instead of 5484, but that doesn't work either. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does rawMessages look like and what does UIDs look like? I'm guessing there is message with a UID of 5484. IMAPClient uses UIDs by default.

Answer (score 8):

Thank you @Madalin Stroe  .

I use python3.6.2 and pyzmail1.0.3 on Win10.
When I run 
`message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessages[4]['BODY[]'])`
The ERR shows like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PATH/TO/mySinaEmail.py", line 42, in <module>
message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessages[4]['BODY[]'])
KeyError: 'BODY[]'
```

When I modified this to `message = pyzmail.PyzMessage.factory(rawMessages[4][b'BODY[]'])`, it run well.

Answer (score 5):

Try replacing ['BODY[]'] with [b'BODY[]']